# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. using Emgu CV

Tags: c#, emgucv

Please guys help me for resolving the issue in the following statement:

```
MCvAvgComp[][] Detector = IMAGEgray.DetectHaarCascade(face, 2.1, 10, 
 Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, new Size(20, 20));"
```

After debugging the solution The compiler show me the following Error:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're dealing with **Haar Cascade** logic, **IMAGEGray** looks to be the gray scale image of type

```
Image<Gray, byte> IMAGEGray;
```

Ensure that it is correctly initialized OR converted rightly from a frame. Basically check that it is not null.

and in this line:

```
IMAGEgray.DetectHaarCascade(face, 2.1, 10, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, new Size(20, 20));
```

**face** is a variable initialized something like:

```
var face = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_some_tree.xml");
```

Ensure that **face** is not null.

If both the variables are not null, then the **DetectHaarCascade** method probably expects some fields in the **face** object to be non-null and it is finding null.

Ensure if the **face** object fields are non-null. (some key ones once the variable is initialized)

Answer (score 0):

Is IMAGEgray a static class? If it isn't then it's probably a null field and the source of your issue.

Otherwise, it sounds like a bug in the method you're calling.

Answer (score -2):

you need to add .xml file in your .../bin/Debug.
Then type in your ProcesFrame Method:
//haar is HaarCascade
haar = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");